# Error on Full calendar function when implementing fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm, fullcalendar

I am facing this error when implementing fullcalendar:

Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined
at HTMLDocument. (main.js:4)

Do I need to define the function somewhere?

Thanks for your help!

Camille

Comment: Hi there. Yes, of course you need to. If the function is not defined before you call it, you'll always get an error. 
Could you please post your relevant code?

Comment: You must have not included the fullCalendar JS file into your page correctly. There are examples at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started